# How to compose AadApplicationToken to insert the data in kusto

Tags: c#, .net, kql

I am learning various techniques of preparing kustoConnectionStringBuilder and also want to ingest the data into kusto table by using it.  Can anyone give examples of how to compose appAccessToken?

```
var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(kustoUri)
    .WithAadApplicationTokenAuthentication(appAccessToken);
var Query = ".ingest inline into table <TableName> <|\rTesting,200.12.1.0,osname,version";
var adminProvider = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslAdminProvider(kustoConnectionStringBuilder);
IDataReader dataReader = adminProvider.ExecuteControlCommand(Query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate manually and provide the token to the above API (see below link for instructions).
That said, KustoConnectionStringBuilder provides many implemented authentication wrappers. Have you considered using those?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/access-control/how-to-authenticate-with-aad